# How to paint multiple objects without reset Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt, paint

I am trying to paint individual cells (20x20px) as I am starting conways game of life. When I click on the screen I paint a cell or I remove it based on the state of the cell within the array. This works, however, only one cell can be present on the screen at any given moment and I am not sure why as the position in the cell array changes if I click on a different part of the screen.

***MAIN CODE***

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class mainApplication extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseListener {


    private static final Dimension windowsize = new Dimension(80, 600);
    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    private static boolean isGraphicsInitialised = false;
    private static int rows = 40;
    private static int columns = 40;
    private static int height = windowsize.height;
    private static int width = windowsize.width;
    private static ArrayList<Cell> cellsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int xArrayElement,yArrayElement, xPosition, yPosition;
    private static boolean gameState[][] = new boolean[rows][columns];


    public mainApplication() {


        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int x = screensize.width / 2 - width / 2;
        int y = screensize.height / 2 - height / 2;

        setBounds(x, y, screensize.width, screensize.height);

        setVisible(true);

        createBufferStrategy(2);

        strategy = getBufferStrategy();

        isGraphicsInitialised = true;

       // MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent();
        addMouseListener(this);
       // addMouseMotionListener(MouseEvent);

        Thread t = new Thread(this);

        t.start();

    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

           int x = e.getX();
           int y = e.getY();

            xArrayElement = (x/20);
            yArrayElement = (y/20);

            xPosition = x - (x % 20);
            yPosition = y - (y % 20);

//      cellList.removeIf(cell -> cell.contains(xPosition, yPosition));

        Iterator<Cell> iterator = cellsList.iterator();

        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (iterator.next().contains(xPosition, yPosition)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        else{

            cellsList.add(new Cell(xPosition, yPosition));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try { //threads entry point
                    Thread.sleep(20); //forces us to  catch exception
                }

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (isGraphicsInitialised) {
            g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

            if(cellsList != null) {

                for (Cell cell : cellsList) {
                    cell.paint(g);
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            }

        this.repaint();
        strategy.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        mainApplication test = new mainApplication();

    }
}
```

***CELLS CLASS***

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Cell {

    int x;
    int y;


    public Cell(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public boolean contains(int xx, int yy) {

        return xx >= x && yy >= y && xx <= x + 20 && yy <= y + 20;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20,20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember my other answer.  As you click on a cell, add that cell to a list of some sort.  When you repaint, go thru the list and repaint all the cells at their location.  This is because each time you repaint you clear the background (which is what you are supposed to do).  So you need to refresh the screen each time. I will write up a quick demo so you can see.

Comment: Hey, sorry I actually uploaded this before I saw your other answer, but I have been trying to figure it out better. I made a list, added  cells, to it. In the paint method i iterate through the list, I paint the cell if theres an element in the list, if not then I make an if statement that paints over any cell that got removed. However nothing is ever painted. I'll just update my code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you do check.  It adds or removes colored squares using the mouse.  To add square, position the mouse somewhere in the panel and click the left button.  To remove, position the mouse over the square and click the right button.  Note that for every mouse click I modify the list and repaint it in its entirety.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AddingSquares {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");

    public AddingSquares() {
        f.add(new MyPanel(500, 500));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // compress various components and invoke any 
        // layout managers.
        f.pack();
        // center on screen
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start on the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new AddingSquares());
    }

}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel(int w, int h) {
        // the following statement won't work unless you
        // do super.paintComponent().
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    }

    List<Square> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int side = 20;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // I prefer graphics2D as it has additional features.
        // Not using any here though.
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (list != null) {
            for (Square sq : list) {
                sq.draw(g2d);
            }
        }

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            // right mouse button removes square
            if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                Iterator<Square> it = list.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    if (it.next().contains(x, y)) {
                        it.remove();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // I want the square drawn with the mouse at the center, not upper left
                // corner, so I adjust the coordinates
                list.add(new Square(x - side/2, y - side/2));
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
    // this could be an external class but it is convenient for this demo.
    private class Square {
        int x;
        int y;
        Color color = Color.blue;

        public Square(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        // used to find the right square to remove
        public boolean contains(int xx, int yy) {
            return xx >= x && yy >= y && xx <= x + side
                    && yy <= y + side;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, side, side);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ugh if only I could code at that level, I've only been using java for about 7 or 8 months so one day I'll get there.  So instead, in the mouse clicked method, you are stating if you right click and there is a square at those co-ordinates, remove it. else you add a new square. Can I ask, how does your contains boolean method work, I'm finding it a bit hard to visualise.

Comment: I store the location of the square at x,y and its side length is side = 20.  Let's say I have a square at 300,200.  So I check to see if the mouse was clicked at any position >= 300 and >= 200 and <= 320 and <= 220.  301,201 returns true, 301, 221 returns false, etc. because the mouse would be outside of that location.

Comment: oh I get it, this is a really neat and logical approach I am busy doing other things but I'll study it more later. Once again thank you so much!

Comment: Hey WJS, I took some of the tools you gave me and modified my code. I updated it in my post so you can see what I have done. I understand its not exactly like how you did it but I wanted to take your tools and implement them in a way that it works with what I already have so that I truly understand it! I am pretty much complete however, when I right click so that the squares are removed, multiple are removed if the sqaures/cells are connected it is like they are treated as one object when they are beside each other and I'm not sure why. You have done enough but the code is there! Thanks a lot!